# Prevent Resubmit of an approved record

Tags: apex

Prevent resubmission of an approved record

Hi,

I have a use case, wherein, if an opportunity record is approved once, the user shouldn't be able to submit it again for approval.

Standard functionality allows resubmitting an approved record.

I know I can prevent it if I use Apex to submit the Approval. But then I'd have to develop custom page too. I want to leverage the standard page and functionality, but want this extra feature.

Can anyone suggest a method with standard functionality to do it?

Comment: In the entry criteria can you add a condition that says if approval process status != approved then allow record to be submitted.if it is already approved then the user will see unable to submit for approval error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the entry criteria can you add a condition that says if approval process status != approved then allow record to be submitted.if it is already approved then the user will see unable to submit for approval error